# Audio cutter native iOS element

Tags: ios, swift, audio, storyboard, crop

I create an app with audio elements, which are stored in File Manager. I need to make crop/trim/cut feature for the records. But I have stuck on UI. I saw a lot of libraries for cut video, but there are nothing for the audio. So my goal to make similar screen and use similar elements as we can see on iPhone audio cutter:

[image]

What is the UI element for audio wave (it is also scrolling when audio plays)? What is the UI element for cutter on audio wave (yellow)? What is the UI element in the bottom for audio cutting feature?

UPD:

I found the [tutorial](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-i-created-apples-voice-memos-clone-b6cd6d65f580) of cloning standart "Voice Memos" app, but without trim feature

Comment: For wave form visualisation may be possible to use https://github.com/bastienFalcou/SoundWave or https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I have tried it, but in a global sense it does't solve the problem :(

Comment: Maybe these would be helpful to start with. Waveform - https://github.com/alternatiph/KNWaveForm, Trim - https://medium.com/macoclock/splitting-audio-with-swift-ba765281c50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI element for audio wave - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64709493/13296047. This post answers exactly how to create a audio wave from recorded audio.

UI element for cutting an audio wave - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062837/13296047

UI element in the bottom for audio cutting feature - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40670853/13296047

This is a very good Voice Memos clone you can use for reference: https://github.com/HassanElDesouky/VoiceMemosClone